# Max family of odd subset of a nested set.

Tags: graph-theory

Hi I have to proof that for $\Omega$ a nested family of odd subsets of $V$ with $V$ finite, we have that $|\Omega|\leq\frac{3}{2}|V|$. I can prove that for certain constructions of $\Omega$, it is satisfies $|\Omega|\leq \frac{3}{2} |V|$, the problem I encounter is that I have to proof that my construction of $\Omega$ is optimal. (Since I have to prove that this holds for every family of odd subsets) Can anyone give me a hint on how to proof that *every* $\Omega$ satisfies this equation.

$\Omega$ is *nested* if for all $A,B\in\Omega$ either $A\subseteq B$, $B\subseteq A$, or $A\cap B=\varnothing$; a set is *odd* if its cardinality is odd.

Comment: What is an "odd subset"? What is a "nested family"? If both of these mean what they sound like they mean, the bound should be $\frac12 |V|$ ...

Comment: Nested family means that for $A,B\in \Omega$, either $A\subset B$, $B\subset A$ or $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Comment: I don't know what tags fit this question. But the set theory tags certainly do not fit here. The [set-theory] one especially.

Comment: Hence if $V=\{v_1,v_2,\dots , v_n\}$ we can choose the sets in $\Omega$ for example as $\{v_i\}$ for all $i \leq n$ and $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ and $\{v_4,v_5,v_5\}$, since they are odd and disjoint or either contained in one another.

Comment: @higuys: Since your use of *nested* is non-standard, I’ve added definitions; please make sure that they are what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality $\Omega$ will contain all the singletons.

Now let $A_0$ be the set of all singletons, and process all *other* sets in $\Omega$ in order of increasing size:

To produce $A_n$, let $B_n$ be the next set from $\Omega$, and let $A_n$ be $A_{n-1}$ *minus* all subsets of $B_n$, *plus* $B_n$ itself.

In each step there will be at least three sets in $A_n$ that are subsets of $B_n$ (because every element in $B_n$ is in *some* element of $A_n$, and they are all odd, and $B_n$ itself isn't there yet).

So the size of $A_n$ drops by at least $2$ for each step. Therefore there cannot be more than $\frac{|V|-1}2$ non-singletons in $\Omega$. So $\frac32|V|$ is an upper bound.

On the other hand, one can always find an $\Omega$ with $\left\lfloor \frac32|V|-\frac12\right \rfloor$ elements, by taking
$$ \Omega = \bigl\{\{1\},\{2\},\ldots,\{|V|\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,3,4,5\},\ldots,\{1,2,\ldots,2n+1\},\ldots\bigr\}$$

Comment: Sorry but I don't completely understand the connection between $A_n$ and the size of non singletons in $\Omega$. I understand that $A$ drops in size by 2 every step. As I see it $A_0=\{\{1\},\dots,\{|V|\}\}$ and then $B_1=\{1,2,3\}$ Hence $A_1=\{\{1,2,3\},\{4\},\dots,\{|V|\}\}$ etc, but how does this process yield all non-singletons in  $\Omega$.

Comment: @higuys: The process doesn't _produce_ the non-singletons in $\Omega$ -- it _consumes_ them one by one. Since consuming a non-singleton makes the size of $A_n$ decrease by at least 2, the number of non-singletons there are to consume can be most $\frac12$ times the size of $A_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a(n)$ be the maximum size of a nested family of odd subsets of $[n]$. We can show by induction on $n$ that $a(n)\le\left\lfloor\frac32n\right\rfloor$. Suppose that $a(m)\le\left\lfloor\frac32m\right\rfloor$ for $m<n$, and let $\Omega$ be a nested family of odd subsets of $[n]$. Let

$$\Omega_0=\{A\in\Omega\setminus\{[n]\}:A\text{ is maximal with respect to }\subseteq\}\;;$$

then $\Omega_0$ is a pairwise disjoint family, and every member of $\Omega\setminus\{[n]\}$ is a subset of some $A\in\Omega_0$. If $\Omega_0=\{A_0\}$ for some $A\subsetneqq[n]$, let $k\in[n]\setminus A_0$; then $\Omega\cup\{k\}$ is a nested family of odd subsets of $[n]$ properly containing $\Omega$, so we might as well assume that $|\Omega_0|\ge 2$. Since $|A|$ is odd for each $A\in\Omega_0$, we have

$$\begin{align*}
|\Omega|&\le 1+\sum_{A\in\Omega_0}a(|A|)\\
&\le 1+\sum_{A\in\Omega_0}\left\lfloor\frac32|A|\right\rfloor\\
&=1+\sum_{A\in\Omega_0}\left(\frac32|A|-\frac12\right)\\
&=1+\frac32\sum_{A\in\Omega_0}|A|-\frac{|\Omega_0|}2\\
&\le\frac32\sum_{A\in\Omega_0}|A|\\
&\le\frac32n\;,
\end{align*}$$

and hence $|\Omega|\le\left\lfloor\frac32n\right\rfloor$, since $|\Omega|$ is an integer.

Comment: If the downvoter found an error, I’d like to know what it is, so that I can fix it (if possible) or delete the answer. As it stands, the downvote is at best useless and at worst vandalism.

Comment: (+1) This is a perfectly good answer. It is crazy how somebody can downvote answers of this quality.

Comment: (+1) Perhaps he/she didn't undestand a solution. I suggest that some limits on down voting should be put, for example to explain why he/she down voted. And the same should be on up voting, sometimes I get up votes on totaly trivial answers and when I do less trivial problem nothing.